# Find the derivative of y = $\sqrt{xe^{2x} + 3e^{-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to find the derivative of this problem but I am not sure where to start. Any help is appreciated.

Find the derivative of $$y = \sqrt{xe^{2x} + 3e^{-x^2}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
$$y=\sqrt{xe^{2x}+3e^{-x^2}}=\left(xe^{2x}+3e^{-x^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
Derivative power rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(y(x)^n)=n*y(x)^{n-1}*\frac{dy(x)}{dx}$$
Therefore:
$$y'=\frac{1}{2}*\left(xe^{2x}+3e^{-x^2}\right)^{\frac{-1}{2}}*\frac{d}{dx}\left(xe^{2x}+3e^{-x^2}\right)$$
Derivative addition/subtraction rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx} (a(x)+b(x))=\frac{da(x)}{dx}+\frac{db(x)}{dx}$$
Therefore:
$$y'=\frac{1}{2}*\left(xe^{2x}+3e^{-x^2}\right)^{\frac{-1}{2}}*\left(\frac{d}{dx}xe^{2x}+\frac{d}{dx}3e^{-x^2}\right)$$
Derivative multiplication rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(a(x)*b(x))=\frac{da(x)}{dx}*b(x)+a(x)*\frac{db(x)}{dx}$$
Derivative constant multiplication rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(c*a(x))=c*\frac{da(x)}{dx}$$
Therefore:
$$y'=\frac{1}{2}*\left(xe^{2x}+3e^{-x^2}\right)^{\frac{-1}{2}}*\left(\left(\frac{d}{dx}x \right)*e^{2x}+x*\left(\frac{d}{dx}e^{2x}\right)+3*\frac{d}{dx}e^{-x^2}\right)$$
Derivative exponentiation rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx}e^{a(x)}=e^{a(x)}*\frac{da(x)}{dx}$$
Therefore:
$$y'=\frac{1}{2}*\left(xe^{2x}+3e^{-x^2}\right)^{\frac{-1}{2}}*\left(1*e^{2x}+x*2*e^{2x}+3*-2x*e^{-x^2}\right)$$
Simplify:
$$y'=\frac{1}{2}*\left(xe^{2x}+3e^{-x^2}\right)^{\frac{-1}{2}}*\left(e^{2x}(1+2x)-6x*e^{-x^2}\right)$$
Putting it into fractional form:
$$y'=\frac{e^{2x}(1+2x)-6x*e^{-x^2}}{2*\sqrt{xe^{2x}+3e^{-x^2}}}$$

Answer (score 0):

## Upgrade

This can be solved using the chain rule's

$y = \sqrt{x e ^ {2x} + 3 e^{-x^2}} $

$ y = ( x e^{2x} + 3 e^{-x^2} )^{\frac{1}{2}} $

$ y' = \frac{1}{2} [(x e^{2x} + 3 e^{-x^2}) ^ {-\frac{1}{2}} ] \cdot ( e^{2x} + 2xe^{2x} - 6xe^{-x^2})$

$ y' = \frac{1}{2} [ (x e^{2x} + 3e^{-x^2}) ^ {-\frac{1}{2}} ] \cdot [ e^{2x} + 2x(e^{2x} - 3e^{-x^2})]
$

Answer (score 0):

"I am not sure where to start".

Derivation has the nice feature that it can be done systematically once you know the rules, which are not that numerous:

- derivative of a sum, a difference, a product, a quotient, a (constant) power;
- derivative of a function of an expression;
- derivative of the elementary functions $e^x, \log x, \sin x, \cos x$, and of course constant ("c" or number) or identity ("$x$");
- derivative of the inverse functions.

In the case at hand, you derive the square root (power $\frac12$) of an expression. The expression is a sum; the first term is the product of $x$ and an exponential function; the second term is the exponential of a square (power $2$).

It suffices to apply the rules in this order.